# AEM 6.5 , how to change Workflow location to Model/subfolder

Tags: workflow, aem

AEM 6.5 default location for Workflow model is : /conf/global/settings/workflow/models/*MyCustomWF*. How can i make the WF model location inside my project folder i.e /conf/global/settings/workflow/models/**My Project**/*MyCustomWF*.
I tried moving my model to  folder via CRX. It result in Model.html page goes blank.And I cant see any option in classic or touch UI to decide the project specific location for the Workflow.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not think that is possible right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer after multiple attempts. You just need to shift your workflow node in the folder(created by you) and go to touch UI and open the new workflow by directly hitting the Workflow MODEL and not navigating through the naviagtion Model tile. After having Model opened in the Edit mode and click on sync model. Now your workflow is in new folder created by you.